# restful web services @POST (creating an user in database) Unsupported Media Type error

Tags: java, web-services, http, post, curl

I've been stuck on this part of my homework for a while, but to no avail. I can get all my @GET methods to work, but not @POST. Here are my implementations:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public Doctor createDoctor(Doctor doctor) throws Exception{
    return dao.createDoctor(doctor);
}
```

my dao method:

```
public Doctor createDoctor(Doctor doctor) throws Exception {
    PreparedStatement query = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DatabaseConnection.getDataSource().getConnection();
        query = conn
                .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO doctor (dId, first_name, last_name, specialty, sex, experience, salary) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        query.setInt(1, doctor.getId());
        query.setString(2, doctor.getFirstName());
        query.setString(3, doctor.getLastName());
        query.setString(4, doctor.getSpecialty());
        query.setString(5, doctor.getSex());
        query.setInt(6, doctor.getExperience());
        query.setDouble(7, doctor.getSalary());
        query.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null)
            conn.close();
    }
    return doctor;
}
```

curl command that i'm calling:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"dId":2,"first_name":"joanna","last_name":"smith","specialty":"eyebrows","sex":"female","experience":1,"salary":1.0}' http://localhost:7001/FirstRestfulService/api/medicalsystem
```

error i'm getting:

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 20 Mar 2014 05:14:17 GMT
Content-Length: 22
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2

Unsupported Media Type
```

get all doctors:

```
    @Path("/doctors")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Doctor> getAllDoctors() throws Exception{
    return dao.getAllDoctors();
    }
```

get all patients:

```
    @Path("/patients")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Patient> getAllPatients() throws Exception{
return dao.getAllPatients();
      }
```

Comment: you need to stringify your JSON data

Comment: POST is going to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: sorry, how do I stringify my JSON data?

Comment: I saw some examples and they have used double quotes for header: -H "Content-Type:application/json". Give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you are doing the request from `Windows` and it doesn't support single quotes `'` around the parameters. Use double quotes `"` instead.

```
-H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

And for JSON object escape the double quotes from inside as well. For example:

```
 -d "{\"dId\":2,\"first_name\": ... and more...}"
```

Also make sure that your json format is correct so that your server can parse it.

Finally add the `-v` parameter with the curl request so that you can see the debug prints of curl on your screen and it will help you a lot.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually figured I needed the escape characters, but I did not know why I needed them. Can you explain why I need a backslash in front of every double quote in my JSON object?

Comment: @user3369362 Because the `JSON` is placed inside the `"..."`. So If you do not escape those, it will be hard for the OS to understand at where the data ended!

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. I have one more question if you don't mind. I don't understand why one of my @GET methods automatically outputs every JSON object uniformally separated by a comma, but my other GET method outputs in a hard to read fashion. Both code are the same. Please refer to my edit of my original post.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot post images to show you exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: I got what you mean. Both look same to me. Its hard to guess anything from here :(

Answer (score 0):

User **@FormParam** annotation in post method and try .

@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public Doctor createDoctor(@FormParam("doctor") Doctor doctor) throws Exception{
    return dao.createDoctor(doctor);
}